# How to plot laplacian noise distribution?

Tags: r, laplacian

I am currently working on Differential Privacy and want to visualize my noise distribution of the data set. I am using Laplacian distribution as my noise addition mechanism.

I have already calculated beta (scale parameter) and the true output of the data set (mean) and wonder which of the Laplace functions I should be using (`dlaplace()`, `plaplace()`, `qlaplace()`, `rlaplace()` from the `rmutil` package) for a noise distribution. I also don't understand why I can't just generate a noise distribution with a Laplace parameter and mean, without specifying the data (`y`,`q`,`p`,`n`) in the functions mentioned above.

My thought of getting the Laplace distribution and visualising it is shown as below:

```
df <- ?laplace(?,m=33.6, s=7.32)
plot(df)
```

? represents the areas that I am unsure about, `m` is the mean and `s` is the scale parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to plot the density:

```r
curve(dlaplace(x, m=33.6, s=7.32), from = 0, to = 66)
```

[image: Laplace density]

`ggplot2` equivalent:

```r
ggplot() + 
   geom_function(fun = function(x) rmutil::dlaplace(x, m = 33.6, s = 7.32)) + 
   expand_limits(x=c(0,66))
```

If you want random deviates:

```r
hist(rlaplace(10000, m = 33.6, s = 7.32), col = "gray", breaks = 100)
```

(the first argument, 10000, is the number of random deviates desired; use `geom_histogram()` in `ggplot`)

[image: Laplace histogram]

Comment: Is there any way I can plot the Laplace pdf with `ggplot2` package?